# C pointer's declaration confusion

Tags: c

What is the difference between these two declarations in C ?

1. `int (*p)(char (*a)[]);`
2. `int *p(char (*a)[]);`

Comment: The first is a pointer to a function. The second is the prototype for a function that returns a pointer. All of the nonsense surrounding the `a` could be replaced with the keyword `void` without changing the question. In other words, it's the same as asking the difference between `int (*p)(void);` and `int *p(void);`

Answer (score 1):

For `int (*p)(char (*a)[]);`:

- `(*p)(char (*a)[])` is an `int`.
- So `(*p)` is a function returns an `int` and takes a parameter of type `char (*a)[]`. (More on the latter below.)
- So `*p` is that same function.
- So `p` is a pointer to that function.
- In `char (*a)[]`, `(*a)[]` is a `char`.
- So `(*a)` is an array of `char`, with unknown size.
- So `*a` is that same array.
- So `a` is a pointer to an array of `char` with unknown size.
- So `p` is a pointer to a function returning `int` that takes a parameter that is a pointer to an array of `char` with unknown size.

For `int *p(char (*a)[]);`:

- `*p(char (*a)[])` is an `int`.
- So `p(char (*a)[])` is a pointer to an `int`.
- So `p` is a function that returns a pointer to an `int` and takes a parameter of type `char (*a)[]`.
- From above, we know that parameter is a pointer to an array of `char` of unknown size.
- So `p` is a function that returns a pointer to an `int` and takes a parameter that is a pointer to an array of `char` with unknown size.